# Convert base64 to pdf and display it in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, pdf, base64

I have an apex that returns a string, and I want this string to decode it and display it as a pdf to a modal in Lightning Web Component. How can I achieve this?
How can I display the pdf without iframe tag?

Here is my simple apex class:

```
public with sharing class getPdfCopy {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static pdfcopy getPdfCopy(String pdfid) {
        pdfcopy response = new pdfcopy();
        response.pdfName = 'test';
        String s = 'JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwog' +
                'IC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAv' +
                'TWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0K' +
                'Pj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAg' +
                'L1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA+' +
                'PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9u' +
                'dAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2Jq' +
                'Cgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJU' +
                'CjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVu' +
                'ZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4g' +
                'CjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAw' +
                'MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9v' +
                'dCAxIDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G';
        response.pdfData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(s).toString();
        return response;
    }
    public class pdfcopy{
        public String pdfName {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String pdfData {get; set;}
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate" >{pdfName}</h2>
    </header>
     <!-- modal body -->
     <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
        <dl class="slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
            <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{pdfData}" id="frame1" width="100%" height ="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </dl>
    </div>
                   <!-- close the modal-->
                   <footer class="slds-modal__footer" >
                    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Close" title="Close" onclick={closeModal}></lightning-button>
                </footer>
            </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>               
        </template>
```

JS:

```
@wire(getPdfCopy,{pdfid: '$pdfNumber'})  
        wiredPdfCopy({ error, data })         
        {
                this.pdfData = data.pdfData;
                this.pdfNumber = data.pdfNumber;
                this.error = undefined;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where pdf is stored? As a Salesforce File?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you did mention that you don't want to use an iFrame to display the PDF. However, if you want to render a Base64 string on demand as an actual document in a LWC using [data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), your only alternative is then to use other HTML elements such as <[object](https://base64.guru/developers/html/object)> or <[embed](https://base64.guru/developers/html/embed)>.

However, I still think that an iFrame is a valid solution here. I have also written a post about it, in which I recommend the approach and explain it step by step:

[How to display and download Base64 encoded PDF documents with Lightning Web Components](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-display-and-download-base64-encoded-pdf-documents-with-lightning-web-components-d4a10c7fa4c3)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi @Sebastiano Schwarz, the solution in your blog doesn't work. When you try to preview a pdf from b64, this message appears in the console "Refused to frame ‘’ because it violates the the Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src blob: ....." and the LWC show the message "This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue." I've tried setup the CSP but I can't solved.

Comment: The solution does work, probably CSP was not configured correctly on your end. Please refer to this thread for the correct configuration to make it work: https://github.com/svierk/awesome-lwc-collection/issues/66